# Choose rows which have same value to make similar-network in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have binary matrix about the relationship between cusID and FPID

```
    f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
c1   0   1   0   0   0   
c2   1   0   0   0   0
c3   1   0   0   0   0
c4   0   1   0   0   0
```

and I want to make a new relationship of cusID.
so I need to make a new matrix of cusIDs who have a relationship with a same FPID

For example, in the matrix above, c1&c4 and c2&c3 have a relationship.
So I need to make this matrix.

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4
c1  0   0   0   1
c2  0   0   1   0
c3  0   1   0   0
c4  1   0   0   0
```

Is there anyone who can solve this problem?

Comment: can you add a MWE?

Answer (score 1):

We need a `crossprod`

```
m2 <- tcrossprod(m1, m1)
diag(m2) <- 0
m2
#   c1 c2 c3 c4
#c1  0  0  0  1
#c2  0  0  1  0
#c3  0  1  0  0
#c4  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: I need to that matrix from the first one. For example, If c1 and c2 have same "1" to f2, ca&c2 have to get 1. It's a kind of complicated.....:(

Comment: @MinjiKim  It is made from the first one i.e. `m1`